# Dockerfile build shell expansion

Tags: dockerfile

Option 1 produces error:

```
> cat Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.6.6-buster
ARG add_source_node="curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -"
RUN set -ex && $add_source_node
> docker build
...
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
curl: option -: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
...
```

Option 2 works:

```
> cat Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.6.6-buster
RUN set -ex && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
> docker build
...# success
```

Why option 1 doesn't work? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

not sure if this will work, but instead of `RUN set -ex && $add_source_node` can you try `RUN set -ex && eval $add_source_node`... $add_source_node is just a string...

Comment: I tested this and can confirm this works. Should be accepted answer.